# change html tags text , on server side (C#, ASP.NET)

Tags: html, tags, server-side

can i change html client tags text , on the server side?

like for example, change h2 or p tags text on server side?

for example:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Welcome to ASP.NET!
</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
</p>
<p>
    You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
        title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
</p>
```

change the h2 text from "Welcome to ASP.NET!" to "Hello".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First add an ID and `runat="server"` to the element:

```
<h2 id="myHeader" runat="server">
```

Then in the `Page_Load` method:

```
myHeader.InnerHtml = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is the `LiteralControl` provided by ASP.NET.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx