# Master page isn't loaded correctly on postBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, postback

First of all, I'm very new to asp.net (Few days worth of experience).
I am using the default content provided by Visual Studio 2013 to work on a Web Forms Application.

**Scenario:** I would like to change the text of a Histamine(h2) after clicking a button.

**Problem:** I am using the default master page provided by Visual Studio but it is not loaded correctly on postBack. From what I can tell the resources it uses for it's layout can't be accessed? I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. If someone could enlighten me I would very much appreciate it.

My code so far:

Default2.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2 id="h1" runat="server">Change me please.</h2>
    <asp:Button ID="b1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="dothis" />
</asp:Content>
```

Default2.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Default2 : Page
{
    protected void dothis(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Header.InnerHtml = "Hello world.";
    }
}
```

Comment: try it, h1.InnerHtml = "Hello world.";

Comment: On a side note, use more meaningful element IDs. A `h2` tag with an ID of `h1` is just confusing. Hopfully this is just a simplified example you are giving.

Answer (score 1):

See [change html tags text , on server side (C#, ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368331/change-html-tags-text-on-server-side-c-asp-net) for the code you need to implement. In your case:

```
h1.InnerHtml = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, instead of using an `<h2>` server control, you can wrap something like a label or literal control within the header tag, like this:

```
<h2><asp:LiteralControl runat="server" id="HeaderLiteral">Change me please</asp:LiteralControl></h2>
```

Then in your code-behind you can do this:

```
HeaderLiteral.Text = "Hello World!";
```

Personal preference but I generally shy away from Server Controls. No particular reason, but offering this suggestion for completeness sake.